# Creating a new CCK field from an imagecache preset?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have an image gallery for which I have configured an Imagecache preset. It's my first time using Imagecache so I am not sure if I am using it right.

Right now, I see that I can only configure the CCK imagefield to show me the imagecache generated image in either the preview or the full node version of the field.

I would prefer to have a new CCK field with the imagecache generated picture. Is this possible? Is there a module for this?

If it isnt, how can I customize my gallery view to show me the preview version of the image, instead of the full node version, which it is currently showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have defined an imagecache preset called `preview`, you can create a view display of your `gallery_image` node type that uses fields rather than node view and selects the field `content_name_of_your_image_field` and set the display of this field to `preview`. If you want to turn this into a gallery, you can link this field to its node, and choose the Grid view style from the menu on the left.

I am guessing that you are probably about half way through these instructions already (unless you are using a horrid image gallery module to create your image gallery).

Comment: Yeah, I was almost done, but I missed the "Format" dropdown list in the image field in views. Now i see that I can choose the imagecache preset in there. Thanks a lot buddy